# How can I find points inside a polygon in ArcGIS server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api

I have a feature class of points. My client wants to draw a polygon on the map to select the subset of points inside the drawn polygon. Is there any tools in ArcGIS API, which I can use it for this purpose? if there is a sample for ArcGIS API for Flex, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/sample-code/select-parcels.htm) available with Flex API. 
[image]

If you are going to work with this functionality and require more advanced features, consider using GP services. See sample [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/flex/sample-code/population-for-any-area.htm).

[image]

Comment: Alex, I have another question for you. Is there any possibility that I can use the same functionality to select features from more than one feature class?

Comment: @Fred, should be. You'd probably need to catch the selection event for multiple services, yet I haven't worked with Flex on this task, cannot guide you here, sorry. Implementing this via GP services can be easily done - you just select features from multiple map services.